# Add text on links using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I want to write relations between 2 nodes on the links that connect them. This is my code, I do not know why he did not work. Can you help me ?
Thanks a lot.

PS: Sorry for my english.

```java
d3.json("links.json", function(json) {
  force
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(json.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.weight); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  link.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#333S")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px");

  link.append("text")
    .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .attr("fill", "Black")
    .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" +
            ((d.source.x + d.target.y)/2) + "," + 
            ((d.source.x + d.target.y)/2) + ")";
    })   
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.relation);
        return d.relation;
    });
  
});
```

This is a links.json example :

```json
{
"nodes":[{"name":"Gaillard Ruzé","group":0},{"name":"Guillaume Budé,Gulielmus Budaeus","group":1}],
"links":[{"source":0,"target":1,"weight":1,"group":15,"relation":"est dédicataire de"}]
}
```

Comment: What does the `links.json` contain?

Comment: nodes : [ {name : ... , group : ...}, {...}] 
links : [{source:..., target:..., weight:1,group:...,relation:...},{...}]

And I want to show relation on links

Comment: You can add the `links.json` data example to your question.

Comment: Ok I do in the 1st post